# how can I add a code before or after spesific element using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser or some alternative class

Tags: html, parsing, dom, addition

How can I add a code before or after a spesific element using PHP Simple HTML DOM?

For example:
before

`<head>` 
add

```
<style> .someclass { text-align:center } </style>
```

output shold be:

```
....
<style> .someclass { text-align:center } </style>
<head>
.....
```

and inside some spesific div how can I add a code for example:

before parsing:

```
<div class="mydiv">...some original staff..</div>
```

after parsing should be:

```
<div class="mydiv"><span>my staff</span>...some original staff..</div>
```

I coldn't figure out. Just I achieved to replace or remove elements. Also woould appreciate if you can suggest alternative method to do this.

Comment: The output is just string? What's wrong with using str_replace?

Comment: but ouptput is coming from another url `$html = file_get_html('http://someurl.com/some.php?id=3965');`

Comment: just to illustrate the problem, can I just str_replace('class="mydiv">', 'class="mydiv"><span>my staff</span>', $html)?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Andrew it worked. I was focused to do it with simple html dom that I didn't think that there is simpler way to do that. this is how to inject element with simple htmldom

```
<?
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://someurl.com');     
$inject  = '<style> .someclass { text-align:center } </style>';
$html->find('head', 0)->innertext = $inject.$html->find('head', 0)->innertext;
echo $html;
?>
```

and this is your suggestion.

```
<?
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://someurl.com');     
$html = str_replace('</head>', '<style> .someclass { text-align:center } </style></head>', $html);
echo $html;
?>
```